# Photos can't be viewed although thumbnails are visible

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos.app

I had an iPhone 5 with photos on it, and it was backed up on iCloud. My iPhone 5 got stolen and I got an iPhone 5s. I restored everything on to my new one, but some photos are there in thumbnail form but I can't view the full pictures. It just shows a blank page and says it is loading... 20+ photos are like this.

Comment: Did the restore take a long time and have you left the device connected to a good speed internet connection for 30 minutes post restore to allow time for things to complete loading?

Comment: It failed, so I tried again and i ran out of icloud space.